# MySQL get attribute which is not present for all possible values of another attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Assume there is a table with columns `fieldA` and `fieldB` (Primary Key:`fieldA, fieldB`). A program keeps inserting entries to this table with the same `fieldA` value, say `constant_for_A`, and some arbitrary value for `fieldB`. In its consistent state, all `fieldA` values are related to all possible `fieldB` values. To ensure this, I am trying to write a procedure that will check which values of `fieldB` might not have been mapped to values from `fieldA` and insert the corresponding row into the table.

As an example, the state of the table, before a new insertion and after the procedure runs are:

1. State 1: No insertions

| fieldA | fieldB |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | X |
| C | X |

2.State 2: After Insertion (fixed value for `fieldA`, arbitrary value for `fieldB`)

| fieldA | fieldB |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | X |
| C | X |
| A | Y |

3. State 3: After the procedure runs

| fieldA | fieldB |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | X |
| C | X |
| A | Y |
| B | Y |
| C | Y |

Once again, whenever a new value for `fieldB` is added, it is always done for a fixed, known value of `fieldA`.

I have tried using joins and nested select queries, however, I can't figure out the correct approach to writing such a procedure. How could this be achieved in MySQL

Comment: No 'checking' required.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, insertions would be required. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 'checking' required, and nothing 'procedural' here. A simple query will suffice:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(fieldA CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,fieldB CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(fieldA,fieldB)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('A','X'),
('B','X'),
('C','X'),
('A','Y');

INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table SELECT x.fielda, y.fieldb FROM my_table x, my_table y;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+--------+--------+
| fieldA | fieldB |
+--------+--------+
| A      | X      |
| A      | Y      |
| B      | X      |
| B      | Y      |
| C      | X      |
| C      | Y      |
+--------+--------+
```